# making animate loop back and forth

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

i want the tail of the fish ".tail_fin" will rotate back and forth 30 deg

here is the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/3XZ59/9/

/* animate this back and forth in a loop */

```
 $('.tail_fin').transition({
      rotate: '+=30deg',
      x: '+=10'
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is what I came up with](http://jsfiddle.net/3XZ59/10/):

```
function flipper(){
    $('.tail_fin').transition({
        rotate: '+=30deg',
    }, function(){
        $('.tail_fin').transition({
            rotate: '-=30deg',
        }, flipper());
    });
}

flipper();
```

Obviously you can mess with it to make it look better.